# Unable to Write Out to PSObject an Array of Data pulled from DB2 database using IBM.Data.DB2 Connector

Tags: powershell, db2

I'm able to extract the data to a CSV file directly when I use  $extractFile = 'D:\TEST\Q_sampler_result_file.csv' when I use Export-CSV to direct to $extractFile.

What is wrong  with how  I'm  using PSObject to bring this  same table  into an array which I would then, if successful direct to an HTML email?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\ME> $factory = [System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories]::GetFactory("IBM.Data.DB2")
PS C:\Users\ME> $cstrbld = $factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder()
PS C:\Users\ME> $cstrbld.Database = 'dbname'
PS C:\Users\ME> $cstrbld.UserID = 'ME'
PS C:\Users\ME> $cstrbld.Password = 'PWD'
PS C:\Users\ME> $cstrbld.Server = 'AIXbox:50001'
PS C:\Users\ME> $dbconn = $factory.CreateConnection()
PS C:\Users\ME> $dbconn.ConnectionString = $cstrbld.ConnectionString
PS C:\Users\ME> $dbconn.Open()
PS C:\Users\ME> $dbcmd = $factory.CreateCommand()
PS C:\Users\ME> $dbcmd.Connection = $dbconn
PS C:\Users\ME> ########################################################################################################################################
PS C:\Users\ME> #DEMONSTRATE --> showing count of how many failed work units in  Application.PFKIWORKUNIT
PS C:\Users\ME> $dbcmd.CommandText = 'SELECT PFIWORKUNIT,ACTOR,FLOWDEFINITION,WORKTITLE,STATUS FROM LAWSON.PFIWORKUNIT WHERE STATUS BETWEEN 0 AND 3'
PS C:\Users\ME> ########################################################################################################################################
PS C:\Users\ME> $dbcmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
PS C:\Users\ME> $da = $factory.CreateDataAdapter()
PS C:\Users\ME> $da.SelectCommand = $dbcmd
PS C:\Users\ME> $ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
PS C:\Users\ME> $rowCount = $da.Fill($ds)
PS C:\Users\ME> $dbconn.Close()
PS C:\Users\ME>
PS C:\Users\ME> write-host $rowCount
10 ##<-- There are TEN rows of data with the five columns named below
PS C:\Users\ME>
PS C:\Users\ME> if($rowCount -gt 0) {
>>
>>
>> $exportObject=@()
>> $Object = New-Object PSObject
>> $ds | ForEach{
>>         $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PFIWORKUNIT" -Value $row.PFIWORKUNIT
>>         $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ACTOR" -Value $row.ACTOR
>>         $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FLOWDEFINITION" -Value $row.FLOWDEFINITION
>>         $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "WORKTITLE" -Value $row.WORKTITLE
>>         $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "STATUS" -Value $row.STATUS
>>         $exportObject += $Object
>> }
>>
>>
>> write-host $exportObject
>> }
>>
@{PFIWORKUNIT=; ACTOR=; FLOWDEFINITION=; WORKTITLE=; STATUS=} ##<-- listing out ONLY Headers of Columns
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of `$row` within the `ForEach` loop. In the context that you are using `ForEach` it is actually short for `ForEach-Object`. When it iterates through an array each iteration is represented by `$_`, but that representation is lost by the time that you want to reference it because you're piping `$Object` to something, so at that point when you reference `$row`, the `$_` value would refer to `$Object`.

What you may want to try is `ForEach($row in $ds){`. That will iterate through `$ds`, and for each item in the array that item will be represented by `$row`. Though, with `$ds` being a dataset, wouldn't you want `$ds.tables[0].rows`? Something like:

```
$exportObjects = ForEach($row in $ds.tables[0].rows){
    [pscustomobject]@{
         "PFIWORKUNIT" = $row.PFIWORKUNIT
         "ACTOR" = $row.ACTOR
         "FLOWDEFINITION" = $row.FLOWDEFINITION
         "WORKTITLE" = $row.WORKTITLE
         "STATUS" = $row.STATUS
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that will end up with `$exportObjects` being the array that you want to be able to convert to HTML. It also avoids the `+=` you were doing before, which is a costly PowerShell process because it destroys and recreates the referencing array each time it happens. Instead I just make objects in the loop, and collect them all in a variable at once.

Comment: The $exportObjects return no data -so I  tried the following which shows 10 rows but  no return of 10 Actors ---  $dbcmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
$da = $factory.CreateDataAdapter()
$da.SelectCommand = $dbcmd
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$rowCount = $da.Fill($ds)
$dbconn.Close()
Write-Host $rowCount
if($rowCount -gt 0) {

ForEach($row in $ds.tables[0].rows){
         
          Write-Host $row.ACTOR
}

Comment: Maybe my reference syntax is wrong. Does `write-host $row['ACTOR']` work? If not, how about just `write-host $row`?

Comment: This seems to work - but results are not in order - for($i=0;$i -lt $ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;$i++)
{ 
  write-host "value is : $i $($ds.Tables[$i].Rows[$i][$i])"
}  For when I echo just $ds.Tables it dumps the data correctly - but when I do this loop it mixes up the columns of data - not sure why its doing that

Comment: `{write-host "value is : $i $($ds.tables[0].Rows[$i])" }` should work. I don't have a dataset to work with, I'm kind of working blind here and trying to remember the last time I did work with a dataset, which was a while ago.